# Cerrar sesión Firebase Auth Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-auth

Estoy trabajando en una app con Firebase Auth en Flutter, la duda que tengo es si hay una manera en la que la sesión del usuario se cierre automáticamente al cerrar la app? He buscado en diferentes lugares pero no encuentro una respuesta concreta, alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, y probablemente termine cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

para hacer algo similar podes habilitar un item en el drawer de la app si lo tiene o un boton en el appbar para cerrar la app, para asi poder usar la funcion de signOut que da la instancia de FirebaseAuth y luego con un exit(0) haces que la app se cierre. Otra alternativa es que al iniciar la app hagas un chequeo de si hay un usuario y si es asi desloguearlo. De todas formas estaria bueno que muestres lo que fuiste probando con código para ayudarte un poco mejor.